# Android Background Location service keeps dying

Tags: android, service, location

The aim of this service is to update the current location of the user in background, I don't want a foreground service. Then every 50 location it writes a GMX file.

The issue I am facing is that the service die for no explicit reason after a random number of updates (and often before 50 location points are generated) and then the service starts again. onDestroy is not called at any time.

Here's the service code (launches with startService):

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
private static LocationManager locationManager;

private final class ServiceHandler extends android.os.Handler{
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper){
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        run(locationManager);



    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i("Service","onHandleIntent lancé");

    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    Log.i("Service","onHandleIntent lancé");

    return START_STICKY; //permet de redémarrer le service s'il est tué
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("DESTROY","IsDestroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

protected void run(LocationManager locationManager){

    Log.i("Service","Service lancé");

    boolean hasLocationFeature = checkLocationFeature();



    if ( hasLocationFeature && (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) ) {
        sLocation(locationManager);
    }


}


protected void sLocation(LocationManager locationManagerArg){

    final List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    final LocationManager locationManager = locationManagerArg;
    Log.i("sLocation","lancé");



    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            saveNewLocation(location);
            if (location != null) {
                locations.add(location);
                Log.i("Locationsize", String.valueOf(locations.size()));
                if(locations.size()%50 == 0) {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gpx");
                    GPXWriter(file, "test1", locations);
                    locations.clear();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,0,locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,5000,0,locationListener);

}
```

The method writing the GPX file has no issue. I have tested this on one emulator and two actual devices, the same problem occurs. It might not be related to memory pressure. I have on my phone other LocationService from other applications that have been running for more than 100 hours.

Why does this service die, and what can I do about this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The OS can kill your service at anytime due to memory constraints,needing more resources, battery saving profiles on the device and even now in Android O the OS kill will kill your service when your app has been in the background for only a few minuets. There is nothing you can do that "guarantees" your service lives forever.

Creating a foreground service is your best option to having a long running service

Comment: Even if I only have 4 process and around 10 services running and I have more than 1 Go or RAM available? seems weird...

Comment: If an app is using up a lot of memory for whatever reason you could have 1 process running and 1 service from another app and a service can still be killed. Its not weird at all thats how android and services work

Comment: Maybe you should read the service `Process Lifecycle` again https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I am aware of all that, it is weird compared to the Happn Location Service which is running for 116 hours in the same environment as mine, and it takes more memory than my service which is more recent...